# Better DB design to have a SUM column, or to constantly add up all relationship items per query?

Tags: database-design

I have a database with an `invoices` table and `invoice_items` table. For simplicity, let's just say the`invoices` table has the following structure:

```
| id | name | created_at |
```

The `invoice_items` has this structure:

```
| id | invoice_id | tital | created_at |
```

Pretty simple, a parent invoice table and the line items go into `invoice_items` with a relationship setup.

What I'm wondering is, how effective it is to has a `sum` column on the `invoices` table? Would it be bad to have all `invoice_items` per invoice added up on the fly to show the invoice total amount? Or would it be better to have a SUM column which is static, and is pulled automatically when invoices are listed - then updated specifically whenever an invoice changes?

Just trying to weigh up the pro's and con's - because whenever an invoice changes, the SUM column needs to be updated whereas if it was just always calculated based on the line items dynamically, would that be a drastic design flaw or be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

As ever - it depends.

If you have a blisteringly quick DBMS or only a handful of items in each invoice, then totalling them up on the fly would be the cleanest (and, therefore, "best") option.

The "Ivory-Tower Database Purists" would say that you should *never* store anything that you can derive dynamically (citing Date-of-Birth vs Age).  Realistically, it depends on just how long it takes to *do* that derivation!

If you have an "ordinary" database, or hundreds or even thousands of items in each invoice *and* you need that summarised total *frequently*, then maintaining the summary field at the Invoice level *might* be the better solution.  [Per-row] Triggers are the way to achieve this, so that *no update* to any item gets missed.

All that said, if I were in your position, I'd go with on-the-fly totalling ...   at least until the application's performance began to suffer, and *then* I'd think about "optimising" this aspect of it.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. That means my approach is correct. Looking at many (if not most) similar situations on older software, there is always a SUM column in the invoices table, but I'll keep on with the on-the-fly totalling for now.